# Can't display Sport Event and Odds from 2 different text files

Tags: python, selenium

My name is Tiago and I'm a begginer trying to code a script to help me with arbitrage betting. Anyways, the script uses selenium to scrape the name of two teams (portuguese soccer teams) and also scrapes the odds of those games. Basically everything works fine, except for when I run the finder_of_surebets.py the output isn't quite what I want.

import itertools
from decimal import Decimal

with open ('sports_event_organizer','r') as namesFile,open('odds_organizer','r') as oddsFile:
name_list = [line for line in itertools.zip_longest(*[namesFile]*2)]
odd_list = [line for line in itertools.zip_longest(*[oddsFile]*3)]
for team, odd in zip(name_list, odd_list):
print(team,odd)
print()

```
The namesFile contains the name of the teams that are going to play in that day. It's a list, and they are supposed to be grouped in pairs! (Example: team a, team b, team c,team d: the matches are supposed to be team a vs team b, team c vs team d)
The oddsFile contains the 3 odds for the 3 possible outcomes (win,draw, lost) , it's not really easy to understand, but take a look at the script and try to understand what I mean.
```

namesFile

```
PORTIMONENSE
CASA PIA
GIL VICENTE
SANTA CLARA
ESTORIL
BOAVISTA FC
CHAVES
FAMALICÃO
SANTA CLARA
SPORTING BRAGA
FAMALICÃO
FC VIZELA
FC AROUCA
ESTORIL
CASA PIA
FC PORTO
MARITIMO
SPORTING CP
BOAVISTA FC
GIL VICENTE
```

oddsFile

```
2.37
3.10
3.00
2.15
3.20
3.35
2.25
3.15
3.15
2.45
3.10
2.85
4.90
3.55
1.70
2.55
3.20
2.67
2.55
3.15
2.72
9.50
5.00
1.29
7.50
4.05
1.42
```

Output: ('PORTIMONENSE\n', 'CASA PIA\n') ('2.37\n', '3.10\n', '3.00\n')
('GIL VICENTE\n', 'SANTA CLARA\n') ('2.15\n', '3.20\n', '3.35\n')
('ESTORIL\n', 'BOAVISTA FC\n') ('2.25\n', '3.15\n', '3.15\n')
('CHAVES\n', 'FAMALICÃO\n') ('2.45\n', '3.10\n', '2.85\n')
('SANTA CLARA\n', 'SPORTING BRAGA\n') ('4.90\n', '3.55\n', '1.70\n')
('FAMALICÃO\n', 'FC VIZELA\n') ('2.55\n', '3.20\n', '2.67\n')
('FC AROUCA\n', 'ESTORIL\n') ('2.55\n', '3.15\n', '2.72\n')
('CASA PIA\n', 'FC PORTO\n') ('9.50\n', '5.00\n', '1.29\n')
('MARITIMO\n', 'SPORTING CP\n') ('7.50\n', '4.05\n', '1.42\n')

is there any cleaner way of doing this? even though the odds are correct and are where they should be, I don't like the amount of \n and '' and ().
Desired Output: Team 1 - Team 2
Odd 1
Odd x (draw)
Odd 2

Team 3 - Team 4
Odd 1
Odd x
Odd 2

Comment: Add to the question - what output do you want to get?

Comment: the output I want to get is per example: